# how to find stdafx.h for Visual studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual studio 2013 for my C++ project. It's required `#include "stdafx.h"` this file. I don't know where to find the stdafx.h source.

Comment: It's the "Precompiled Header" file generated by Visual Studio. It should already be in your project filesystem somewhere, if not, try building your project to recreate it.

Comment: You create it yourself. Everything included in this header file are headers from third party libraries or even your own headers that don't change often.

Comment: Unless you know what precompiled headers are and how to use them properly you're best just turning that feature off.

Comment: how do i create it. I tried to build but it end up with error

Comment: ***how do i create it.*** The same way you create any other header file in Visual Studio. On the File Menu select new then file and follow the prompts. Or press `ctrl-n`

Comment: I can make stdafx.h and add it my project. but i don't know which is the source code should I put in there?

Comment: You can leave it blank. Or add includes for the standard library like `#include <iostream>` you don't put source code in that file.

Comment: I predict the next question will be about why it doesn't work when it's not the first include, or why it doesn't work because there's no file set to create the precompiled header correctly. Really, it's no help to you, turn it off until you understand why you might need it.